# output variable in docker image FROM statement to file

Tags: docker

In the below dockerfile I am trying to output the version of `FROM` to `file.txt`. The image builds, but `$VER` in `file.txt` is empty. Thank you :)

```
ARG VER=4.0.5

FROM <base>:${VER}

WORKDIR /path/to

ARG VER=$VER

RUN echo base ${VER} > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
ARG VER=4.0.5

FROM <base>:${VER}

WORKDIR /path/to

ARG VER

RUN echo base ${VER} > file.txt
```